# Why does the sequence $a_n = (n^2)(1 - \cos(\frac{4.4}{n}))$ converge to 9.68?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

> Find the limit of the sequence whose terms are given by $a_n = (n^2)(1 - \cos(\frac{4.4}{n}))$.

The given answer for this problem is $9.68$. What rules about sequences, and steps, should be taken to show that this sequence converges to $9.68$?

Comment: What is the sequence?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Taylor series. $\frac{4,4}{n}$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, so you can use the Taylor serie of $\cos$.

Thus you have : $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$. So you have :

$$a_n=n^2 ( 1-1+\frac{(\frac{4.4}{n})^2}{2} +o(\frac{1}{n^2}))$$

Finally :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\frac{4.4^2}{2}=9.68$$

Answer (score 1):

You could use L'Hopital's Rule.  First, you have to rearrange the sequence so that it fits into the indeterminate form that L'Hopital's Rule requires (either $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$).

$$n^2\left(1-\cos{\frac{4.4}{n}}\right)=\frac{1-\cos{\frac{4.4}{n}}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

The right hand side of the above equation approaches $\frac{0}{0}$ so L'Hopital's Rule applies. Taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator gives:
$$\frac{\left(\frac{-4.4}{n^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{4.4}{n}\right)}{\frac{-2}{n^3}}=\frac{\frac{4.4}{2}\sin\left(\frac{4.4}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

This is still an indeterminate form so apply L'Hopital's Rule again.
$$\frac{\frac{-4.4*4.4}{2n^2}\cos\left(\frac{4.4}{n}\right)}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}=\left(\frac{4.4\cdot4.4}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{4.4}{n}\right)$$

Take the limit as n approaches $\infty$ and you get
$$\left(\frac{4.4\cdot4.4}{2}\right) = 9.68$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. As $x \to  0$, by the Taylor series expansion, one has
$$
\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}2+O(x^4)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\cos \left(\frac{4.4}n \right)=1-\frac{4.4^2}{2n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4} \right)
$$

Notice that 
$$
\frac{4.4^2}{2}=9.68.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe you know that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sinx}{x}=1$$.

You have to convert the problem so that you can use the above formula. For example start with $n=\frac{1}{x}$

Let me know if you can solve it or need more help.